# Using itemize, can we list the items like a_1, a_2, a_3

Tags: itemize

```
\newcommand{\subscript}[2]{$#1 _ #2$}
\begin{itemize}[label=(\subscript{a}{{\arabic*}})]
    \item
    Generated by the vvv
    \item
    Generated by the ccc
\end{itemize}
```

Using itemize, can we list the items like a_1, a_2, a_3.

Please provide me a method. I do not want to use enumerate

Comment: Please explain why you do not want to use enumerate? It is literally made for this. Itemsize is for static labels.

Comment: And please don't show a code snippet only. Always try to show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964).

Comment: You are right. I understand

Comment: I don't understand why this posting was closed. What wasn't clear?

Comment: I guess it could be argued that it's not clear what's so bad about enumerate.  Also whether OP wants to avoid the package or the environment (but *why* is more important).

Comment: @Teepeemm - In my view, a productive approach to handling a puzzling claim -- such as the OP's stated desire to avoid using an enumerate environment -- is to provide a sensible answer that, as an aside, demonstrates that the puzzling claim is pretty much irrelevant. I see no point in wanting to make the OP admit the error in his/her ways first, kind of like inflicting some sort of ritual punishment, before we deign provide an answer.

Comment: @Mico There isn't a MWE in the question, but it uses an `itemize` environment with optional argument. So it is even unclear how this environment is defined. So IMHO the questioner should not only explain, why not use enumerate, but also extend the code snippet to a MWE.

Comment: @cabohah - "[I]t is even unclear how this environment is defined." The only way I know of how to make a construct such as `\begin{itemize}[label=(\subscript{a}{{\arabic*}})]` have a remote chance of being legal is to load the [enumitem](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package. In my experience, making somebody justify and defend a misguided claim (such as not wanting to employ an `enumerate` environment) is hardly ever productive. Giving them a good solution is far more likely to succeed in making them realize that their claim was misguided and, to boot, irrelevant.

Comment: @Mico I think a puzzling claim like that is usually a sign of an XY problem.  So if we can get OP to elaborate on what they're actually doing and why they think their puzzling claim is proper, then we stand a chance of solving their stated problem and also solving their Y problem more appropriately.  (And if OP had originally meant they can't use the `enumerate` package, then using the `enumitem` package is either appropriate (because `enumitem` is why they couldn't use `enumerate`) or not (because they don't have extra packages installed?).)

Comment: @Teepeemm - Thanks. You make some interesting points. In view of the fact that my answer (in which I blithely ignored the OP's "no enumerate environment" wish) got the OP's checkmark, I'm actually fairly confident that we need not to be overly concerned that an XY problem was present here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend you use an `enumerate` environment rather than an `itemize` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=a\textsubscript{\arabic*}]
\item aaa
\item bbb
\item ccc
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you want the labels to be typeset in math mode rather than in text mode, simply replace

```
[label=a\textsubscript{\arabic*}]
```

with

```
[label=$a_{\arabic*}$]
```

No need to create a separate `\subscript` macro.